# Unable to load google ajax components from the network...you can add &html to the url as a workaround

Tags: python

My python program contains 'n' times the below snippet of code.I only change the 'url' each time. When I run my python program I get separate output for each http request. These outputs are written into the file.
Some of the responses doesn't come up in the file.There is just blank where I expect the response for that particular http request. However If I were to take the code snippet for http request that fails to a separate py file that does works as expected. I call fp.flush() after every single write in my python program. I can't figure out what else might be going wrong.It would be great If anyone can point it out. If I view the output html file in text format, in the section where the URL failed, I get the following error message.

> 'Unable to load google ajax components from the network...you can add
>   &html to the url as a workaround...'

Can someone point out to me what is wrong here.?

```
fp = open("output.html","wb")

url='https://localhost:9006/opexxxons?metxxcs'
r = requests.get(url,auth=('admin','admin'),verify=False)
if True:
        fp.write('<br><br>')
        fp.write('<b>' + url + '</b>' + '<br>')
        fp.write('<br><br>')
        fp.write(r.text)
        fp.flush()
else:
        fp.write(url + 'Failed')
```

Comment: What is the problem and what is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye - Please see the update question description

Comment: Isn't the `if True` redundant? :-)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu - Yes that is true.I had a check for response code = 200. But just to make sure that it prints anyways

Comment: Then it sounds like a problem with the web server.

Comment: It is possible you are requesting too frequently.

Comment: You need to consider closing the file. if you open file in every code snippet, then I think you must close in 'if' and 'else' clauses

Comment: @Optimus - I am not closing the file every time.The file is closed only at the very end.Please see updated question.

Comment: @cziemba - I have tried putting in sleep(30) still get back the same result.Please see updated question.